# Solve $\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}= x^2y$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> **Question:**
>
> Find the particular solution of the following PDE using separation:
> $$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x \partial y}= x^2y$$
> such that \begin{align} z(x,0)&= x^2 \\ z(1,y) &= \cos{(y)}\end{align}

**My attempt:**

\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\bigg) &= x^2y \\ \therefore \int \partial\bigg( \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \bigg) &= \int x^2y \partial x \\ \implies \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} &= \frac{1}{3}x^3y + F(y) \\ \therefore z(x,y) &= \frac{1}{6}x^3y^2 + \int F(y) \partial y + G(x) \\ &= \frac{1}{6}x^3y^2 +M(y) + G(x)\end{align}

This is where I am stuck, however. I cannot seem to find a way to solve the two unknows equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the initial conditions:

$$z(x,0)=G(x)=x^2$$
$$z(1,y)=\dfrac{1}{6}y^2+M(y)+1=\cos(y)\Longrightarrow M(y)=\cos(y)-1-\dfrac{1}{6}y^2$$

Your solution then reads:
$$z(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{6}x^3y^2+x^2-1-\dfrac{1}{6}y^2+\cos(y)$$
And you can verify that it indeed satisfies the PDE:
$$\dfrac{\partial^2z}{\partial x\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}x^2y^2+2x\right)=x^2y$$

Answer (score 1):

$z(x,0)=x^2$ implies that $M(0)+G(x)=x^2$, and in particular here $M(0)$ is just a constant, and for equation to hold for all $x$ we simply need $$G(x)=x^2-M(0)$$.

Similarly $z(1,y)=\cos y$ implies $$\frac{1}{6}y^2 +M(y)+G(1)=\cos y \implies M(y)=\cos y - \frac{1}{6}y^2 -G(1)$$

So $M(0)=1-G(1)$ and $G(1)=1-M(0)$

Choosing any constant value for $G(1)$ (or $M(0)$) gives a set of solutions, and this means your solution is not unique, in particular.

You could choose, for instance, $M(0)=0$